# How to convert a string with key value pairs into a list of dictionaries?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to migrate my playbooks into ansible tower environment. In my playbook, I defined variables like db_list:

```
db_list:
   - { dbid: 1, dbname: abc}
   - { dbid: 2, dbname: xyz}
```

in tower survey, I can put similar info as textarea in survey:

```
dbid: 1, dbname: abc
dbid: 2, dbname: xyz
```

How can I convert my textarea data into a list of dictionary? I can't find any suitable jinj2 filter for conversion.

my ansible version is 2.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the contents of the textarea are in a variable called `textarea`, you can take advantage of the fact that yaml is pretty liberal:

```
- set_fact:
    db_list: >-
      {{ textarea.split("\n") | select | 
         map("regex_replace", "^", "- {") | 
         map("regex_replace", "$", "}") | 
         join("\n") | from_yaml }}
```

Where that `select` in the pipeline is designed to strip off any empty lines (since those lines will not be True-thy)

Comment: this works!  i replaced double quotes with single quote